# input a list of numbers and 'void' type not allowed here

Tags: java, input, void

Below is my preliminary script.

```
public class Insertion
{
    public static void sort(double[] a)
    {
        int N = a.length;
        for (int i=1; i<N; i++)
        {
            for (int j = i; j>0; j--)
            {
                if (a[j-1] > a[j])
                    exch(a, j-1, j);
                else break;         
            }
        }
    } 

    public static void exch(double[] a, int i, int j)
    {
        double swap = a[i];
        a[i] = a[j];
        a[j] = swap;     
    }   
    
    public static void main(String[] args)    
    {            
        double[] a = {5, 2, 4, 1};  //eventually wanna be able to input this in interactions
        System.out.println(a[1]);      //just trying to figure out what's going on here
        System.out.println(a.length); 
        System.out.println(sort(a));   
    }
}
```

If i run it, i get the following error message for `System.out.println(sort(a));`

`Error: 'void' type not allowed here`

So I have two questions:

1. what do they mean by void not allowed and how do you resolve this issue?
2. As you may have noticed, i'm hand typing in `double []a` because I still havent been able to figure out how to input a list of numbers when executing a java script.

---

## Edit:

this is after I made the changes recommended to me

```
public class Insertion
{
 public static double[] sort(double[] a)
  {
     int N = a.length;
     for (int i=1; i<N; i++)
     {
         for (int j = i; j>0; j--)
         {
           if (a[j-1] > a[j])
               exch(a, j-1, j);
           else break;         
         }
     }
     return a;
   } 
    public static void exch(double[] a, int i, int j)
    {
     double swap = a[i];
     a[i] = a[j];
     a[j] = swap;     
     }   
        public static void main(String[] args)    
    {            
         double[] a = {5, 2, 4, 1};
           System.out.println(a);
         //System.out.println(sort(a));   
          // sort(a);
           System.out.println(sort(a));
    }
}
```

As output of the script as written above, i get the following `[D@3e9af3ee`

Comment: The error message is clear enough. What do you not understand about it?

Comment: @Raedwald sorry im just beginning to use java.  That issue has been addressed though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your method doesn't have a return stataement  `public static void sort(double[] a)` for that you cant print `System.out.println(sort(a));`.

Try to change it in something like this:

```
   public static double[] sort(double[] a){
   ...
   return a;
   }
```

In main method do this to iterate the array:

```
  for(double db: sort(a)){
   System.out.println(db);
  }
```

Comment: so i made the changes you mentioned to `sort`, but in the main,  i get `[D@260e3226` as the output of `System.out.println(sort(a))` .  Also, the funny thing is, even before sort function is getting called up, if i do `System.out.println(a)`, it also outputs `[D@260e3226`   (im gonna attach the current version in the OP so you can see it better)

Comment: im curious why you cant just  `System.out.println(sort(a));` instead of ` for(double db: sort(a)){
   System.out.println(db);
  }`     Your suggestion does give me the right answer but i was hoping to be able to print it out as a single list, instead of individual numbers in different lines

Comment: @stratofortress try to use "Arrays.asList" to convert array to list

Answer (score 0):

Since the method  `sort(a)`     **doesn't return anything** you can not do  `System.out.println(sort(a));`

**What is the println funtion getting as args??**

Answer (score 0):

The return type of `sort` method is `void`, which is to say "nothing".

`System.out.println(sort(a));` - here you are asking to print a value returned by a call `sort(a)` which is `void` and not allowed. That's the error - you can't print out "nothing".

Change the return type of the `sort` method to `double[]` and return `a` from `sort` method or split the call to `sort` as follows -

```
   sort(a);
   System.out.println(a);
```